# Autocomplete and syntax highlighting stopped working since upgrading to Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1042b

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6

Syntax highlighting looks like this:

[image]

It happens not only on my Mac, but also on my colleague's Mac.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue. A temporary fix is to go to another file and then back to the original file in the editor. This will reset the highlighting and make it a little bit more bearable.

Submit a bug report at [Apple's Bug Reporting Site](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Certainly annoying, though.